# Name of a mild generalization of linear function: $F[x]=a_1\phi(x_1)+a_2\phi(x_2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

Consider a linear function $G$ on $\mathbb R^3$. It is usually written as:

$$G[x]=(a_1,a_2,a_3)\cdot (x_1,x_2,x_3)$$

where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is a point in $\mathbb R^3$.

Assuming continuity, it is very interesting that $G$ is a linear functional **if and only if** $G(x+y)=G(x)+G(y)$.

I am considering a generalized linear function, $F$, such that $F[x]=a\cdot (\phi(x_1),\phi(x_2),\phi(x_3))$, where $\phi$ is an increasing real function.

$F(x+y)\neq F(x)+F(y)$ but it is the case that: $F(x)=F(y)$ and $x_1=y_1$ implies that $F(x+ce_1)=F(y+ce_1)$, where $c$ is any constant and $e_1$ is unit vector on the first axis.

It can also be further generalized to "generalized linear functional" where $x$ is a point of the space of real functions.

**My question: what is the name of this "generalized linear function(al)"?** What is a simple "if and only if" condition for this generalized linear function?

Without knowing its name it is very difficult for me to search more texts or literature on this topic.